# How to disable 3rd party apps installation setting

Tags: android, configuration

Yes, it is possible to enable/disable 3rd party apps installation (not from Google Play) in Android settings. But I need to permanently disable 3rd party apps.

This is a requirement of the customer of our special Android based, pre-rooted devices. Is it possible to remove this from the settings? Or prevent the user from being able to change it?

Answer (score 0):

The setting in question requires `WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS` permission, which is only granted to system applications. There is no way to change it, or block users from changing it, via any third party application.

The core setting can be modified like so:

```
Settings.Secure.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS, 0);
```

But this will only work if you use root access to install your apk to the system partition in order to have the `WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS` permission granted.

Comment: Maybe it is possible to change some system configuration file? Device is rooted of course. It would be nice to know where is this setting stored. Thanks.

Comment: Added the call to disable the setting, but as mentioned, you'd need to make the app a system app for this to work, which is beyond the scope of the question.